# Will dipping in to savings affect mortgage possibillities?

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom

I currently have 2 accounts; a savings, and a current.
*Each month I have an amount transferred over to the savings*.

Since I have saved for a number of years now I have enough for a reasonable deposit on a house, but I am worried my spending habits will lower my chances of getting a good mortgage.

Each month I transfer a small amount from my savings back to my current account. It would usually be around £100, *which I pay back* with my next transfer to my savings.

I always put the money back in, but I wondered if this would look bad on a mortgage application in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply for a mortgage with someone other than your current / savings account provider, they will not have access to this level of information.

They will pull your credit report, which contains information about debts and credit cards (repayments, amount borrowed etc.) and overdrafts, as well as anything like CCJs against you, but has no information about current or savings accounts other than who your main current account provider is.

You can (and should) check your credit report yourself, to make sure there's nothing incorrect on there. This only costs a few pounds and you can find out about how to do this from the 3 main agencies here: https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/articles/how-to-check-your-credit-report

If you apply for a mortgage with the same provider that you use for your current account and savings account, they could theoretically look at your account usage history in this level of detail. However, I would be very surprised if they had a problem with the type of activity you describe. They'll be looking more at whether you have regular income into your account, whether you have frequently gone overdrawn without permission, etc. Moving money around between accounts or having a fluctuating savings account balance is not even slightly a red flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have made an appointment with a few mortgage advisors, and they all requested by current and saving account statements for the past 3 months. That is what made me want to ask this question. (It is a shame I don't have 15 rep so I can upvote your answer to say thanks)

Comment: OK, this is because they want to see that a) you actually have the deposit and b) you have not just suddenly got a big lump of money from an unknown source. (If you have it might imply you have borrowed money for the deposit, which would concern them).